# How to retrieve streamingdata from dataservice and use it in Pentaho CDE Dashboard?

Tags: streaming, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, dataservice

I'm trying to display incoming streamingdata in a Pentaho dashboard. The incoming data are simple strings, which I would just like to display at the dashboard for now.

I created a kettle transformation, in which I bound a dataservice to the last step(MQTT-Producer).
Within spoon, I tested the service and it seems to work fine.
After uploading the kettle file, the service showed up in the service list (http://localhost:9090/pentaho/kettle/listServices).
Working with the dashboard editor, I use 'streaming over dataservices' from the 'DATASERVICES Queries' as my datasource.
At this point I didn't seem to have any success an was just trying out different panel options and dataservice properties.

I was following those tutorials:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Data_Services

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/CTools/Create_Streaming_Service_Dashboard

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

cheers

update:

I changed the incoming streaming data to be two doubles.
after some more playing around, I did connect to the data service, using an external tool. I did see the expected values within the database. My dashboard, however, still shows this error message:

*Error processing component (ccclinechart)*

The same kind of error occurs, when I try to view the sample real time dashboard. It can't process the chartComponent. Maybe I need to reconfigure some other things?

Comment: give one step let's say dummy after your webservice tab and use that step as input and try.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. I'm not sure what you are trying to say, sorry. I assume, you want me to add another step (dummy) at the end of my Transformation(after my dataservice), to verify, that the transformation works properly. However, I can assure that it does work. I used an external DB-tool, to connect to Pentahos database. I did see the expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake.

Something went wrong with the Ports. After switching back to the default(8080) it worked just fine.

There might be another way to adjust your ports-settings to the problem, but the easiest way to deal with this sort of thing is to switch back to default settings.